# Consul Through SSH VPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, vpn, openssh, consul

I'm attempting to connect an existing cluster to a remote AWS EC2 instance. I'm using OpenSSH (ssh -w) to create tunnel device something like this:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH_VPN

I'm trying to connect one of my consul servers running linux to the AWS instance also running linux (ubuntu 14.04).
I can get the tunnel setup and ping each machine however thats where I start to get fuzzy on what to do next.
I have a private IP address on eth0 of 10.x and a 192.x on tun0.

Which one should I bind consul to?
How can I make it so the other Consul Servers know how to connect to AWS through this connection?
I would like vault running on each of the 3 local servers to be available from AWS

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with OpenSSH. Consul 0.5.2

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I am trying to have a similar configuration.

If you bind consul to `0.0.0.0` it will listen to all interface.
If you bind to `127.0.0.1` it will just listen just to the loopback interface.

If you want each consul to be able to discover the other, I think you'll need a host server vpn, N client vpn. 

I wonder if one server will be enough or if each nodes need to have one server, did you solve this out?

Comment: I havent solved the issue yet but I did read in the documentation that if you send a request to the local agent that for a remote datacenter the local agent will forward that request to a random server in the remote datacenter. I think this means that all servers regardless of datacenter need to be connected mesh style. You can read at the bottom of this doc https://www.consul.io/docs/guides/datacenters.html

Comment: Did you test UDP traffic over your tunnel?